# Get information from another table with JOIN

Tags: sql, database, join

Currently, I have this SQL query to try getting the information from `collection_actors`:

```
SELECT ca.id_imdb AS IMDb_ID,
       caat.id_collection AS collection_ID,
       ca.data_name AS actors_name

FROM collection_actors AS ca
JOIN collection_actors_assignedto AS caat
ON ca.id_imdb = caat.id_collection
WHERE caat.id_collection = 'tt1104001'
```

Here's the database for both tables:

```
collection_actors
    id
    id_user
    id_imdb
    data_name
    date_birth
    date_added
    date_edited
    information_ipaddress


collection_actors_assignedto
    id
    id_user
    id_actor
    id_collection
    date_added
    information_ipaddress
```

The problem is that I can't get any information from `collection_actors` at all, even if there's data to match the IMDb ID! How can I get this to work?

Comment: What is the data type of `id_collection`? if it defined as `int` use `WHERE caat.id_collection = tt1104001` instead.

Comment: I think you mean _tables_, not _databases_? If so, please correct title & question accordingly.

Comment: Are you sure you have a caat.id_collection = 'tt1104001' in your `collection_actors_assignedto` table?

Comment: @CBroe Thanks. I've missed that :)

Comment: @reos Yes. I'm sure about it

Comment: @MahmoudGamal The data type for `id_collection` is `VARCHAR` since it will contains characters and numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a go with this sql snippet, this is based on your code but you need to make sure that the value in id_collection matches data in the id_imdb field otherwise you'll never get any results.

```
SELECT ca.id_imdb AS IMDb_ID
, caat.id_collection AS collection_ID
, ca.data_name AS actors_name
FROM collection_actors AS ca
INNER JOIN collection_actors_assignedto AS caat ON ca.id_imdb = caat.id_collection
WHERE caat.id_collection = 'tt1104001'
```

Comment: Thanks but either yours or Matheus Lopes queries works. I have tried to write both `$actor['name']` and `$actor['actors_name']` in my `foreach` loop for these queries (tested after each other) - the results are empty (no data is shown)

Comment: This should work as long as there is relevant matching data in the two tables. Also for reference, its not a loop, its a SQL query ;)

Comment: Yea. It did work too :) I missed that `id_collection` is for the movies ID and not the actors ID. `caat.id_collection` will therefore be `caat.id_actor`. A simple mistake from my part *ashamed* Thanks you so much :D And to loop out the actors I need a loop function such as `foreach` ;) But I know what you mean :)

Comment: No problem, glad you got to the bottom of it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
SELECT ca.id_imdb AS IMDb_ID,
       caat.id_collection AS collection_ID,
       ca.data_name AS actors_name

FROM collection_actors AS ca, collection_actors_assignedto AS caat
WHERE (ca.id_imdb = caat.id_collection) AND (caat.id_collection = 'tt1104001')
```